# How to make status indicators that depend on child status indicators?

Tags: 2010, web-part, content-query-web-part, kpi

We've been tasked with using SharePoint 2010 to create a dashboard for at-a-glance production line status.
The line is broken into different areas each with their own status indicator:
 
 green when no problems and 
 red when production in that area is down.
Each area has 3 sub-areas that each have their own status indicators.
We need the line area indicators to depend on their sub-area indicators i.e. a given area indicator would turn green only if all it's sub-areas are green.

Is this possible with SP2010, without the use of dashboard designer (we don't have this functionality)?

I was working off a blog http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/06/26/case-study-kpi-roll-up-in-moss-2/ which is similar to what we want to achieve but doesn't have the dependence relationship between indicators that we require.

Are there any other approches that you could recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and ended with custom developed web part which was displaying tree items with statuses. There was a timer job running every ~10 minutes to recalculate all the values. First were calculated leaf statuses and then just going up in the tree. The algorithm for this can be very dummy and time consuming or you can use one of tree traversal algorithms to gain best performance.

Comment: Thanks, Luccio. Would you mind providing a bit more detail about how to implement this? Specifically how did you create child/parent relationships, and how did you make the statuses of the parent depend on the children?

Comment: I had one list with lookup column into this list. So that is how you get the parent/child relationship. Then you just have to create query to list and create some kind of structure which is easy to traverse (both ways). e.g. linked list, hashmap, ...Start to "calculate" status from leaves - you can have some kind of rule to set the status (mine was choice field). Then you go up in the tree and just compare the status of the parent and the child. In my case, I had states Cancelled, Pending, Approved. When any child was in state Cancelled, the parent displayed Cancelled. Hope you get the idea.